# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() has already been called

Tags: android, screen-orientation, illegalstateexception, android-configchanges

I want my app to handle manually orientation changes.
So that why I implemented `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`, as below:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        applyOverrideConfiguration(newConfig);
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

But, when my app is running, and I just turn my device, then, my app crash and I get these logs:

> 12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E
>   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich          Process:
>   fr.zwedge.becomerich, PID: 22290 12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E
>   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() has already been
>   called 12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime
>   fr.zwedge.becomerich          at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(ContextThemeWrapper.java:64)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at
>   fr.zwedge.becomerich.activity.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:1116)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4037)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4113)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1435)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 12-11
>   13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 12-11 13:18:47.522 22290
>   22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 12-11
>   13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-11
>   13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 12-11 13:18:47.522
>   22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
>   12-11 13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 12-11
>   13:18:47.522 22290 22290 E   AndroidRuntime fr.zwedge.becomerich
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Don't know what's going wrong. Hoping someone can explain me, and help me, Darkball60

Answer (score 0):

The method `ContextThemeWrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration` can be called only once, and it checks if resources have been accessed. Check your code if you also have a call to applyOverrideConfiguration in the constructor, that happened to me once.

Also check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#applyOverrideConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration)).

Comment: Checked this, and no, I didn't use this method before.